# Jquery UI DRAG/DROP, one div works the other does not. how to fix?

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop

I have the following Jquery UI drag and drop jsfiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/zoojsfiddle/ud96jdcp/

```
     <div class="dragImg"><img class="img" src="http://www.thumbshots.com/Portals/0/Images/Feature%20TS%201.jpg"></div>  

    <div id="drag1" class="dragImg" title="Start Button"></div> <!-- end of drag1 -->            

   <div id="dropHere"></div>
```

The div with the larger icon works 1st div, you can drag and drop and move around in the bordered div, and have it contained.
The div with the smaller icon, 2nd div, will not allow drag and drop.
As far as I can see they result in the same div , just the 2nd one uses a css.
How do I fix the 2nd div to get drag and drop to work.
Thanks for looking.

Answer (score 0):

Your second draggable needs content to drag. Maybe add the image element to #drag1:

```
        <div id="drag1" class="dragImg" title="Start Button"><img class="img" src="http://www.thumbshots.com/Portals/0/Images/Feature%20TS%201.jpg"></div>
```

then add some style to the image element in #drag1:

```
#drag1 .img{
width:32px;
height:32px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It does the drag on the div you have class="dragImg" but since it doesn't have any underlying tag, it appears it doesn't. All you have to do is to wrap div with id="drag1" inside another div with class="dragImg".

```
<div class="dragImg">
        <div id="drag1" title="Start Button">          
        </div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ud96jdcp/6/

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your second element "#drag1" . There is nothing for the function to clone. It requires some sort of inner HTML dom structure.
The first one works because it is cloneing the image and appending it to your drop zone.

Try it with this as your second element:
https://jsfiddle.net/ud96jdcp/11/

In this version I modifed the css to add the background image to the .test class instead of #drag1
https://jsfiddle.net/ud96jdcp/13/

```
<div id="drag1" class="dragImg" title="Start Button"><div class="test">testing</div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: you are dragging a div into your target, the css is just missing.

Longer answer: You can change the css in your fiddle to

```
.drag1 {
    margin-left:15px;
    margin-top:15px;
    background-image: url("http://www.thumbshots.com/Portals/0/Images/Feature%20TS%201.jpg");
    width:32px;
    height:32px;
}
```

and the html portion to

```
<div id="drag1" class="dragImg drag1" title="Start Button"></div> <!-- end of drag1 -->
```

and you will be able to see the divs that you have been successfully dragging and dropping all along.

DEMO: https://jsfiddle.net/Lbt28duj/